# How to design this function efficiently?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have the below UpdateCustomer function. The problem I'm running into is that I want ValidCustomer function to work by itself and not require existing customer object. In other words it should be calling the database to get the existing customer and do all the complex business rules checking. If I do that I will be calling the database multiple times since CustomerDataChanged function also requires existing customer object. What is the best way to design this function? Is there a design pattern I could follow to refactor this?

```
public string UpdateCustomer(Customer CustomerToUpdate)
{

  Customer ExistingCustomer = GetExistingCustomerFromDataBase(CustomerToUpdate.ID);

  string ErrorMessage = ValidCustomer(CustomerToUpdate, ExistingCustomer);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage)) {
       bool DataChanged = CustomerDataChanged(CustomerToUpdate, ExistingCustomer);

       if (DataChanged) {
          UpdateCustomer(CustomerToUpdate);
       }
    }
  return ErrorMessage;

 }
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com for working code.

Comment: I wouldn't even bother about trying to optimise the double-load away unless it becomes a bottleneck in your application. And if you're using `Find`, EF will cache the result for you anyway. If you absolutely need this optimisation, an overload which *doesn't* take an existing customer should load it and pass it into your current `ValidCustomer`. As an aside, it probably should be named Valid***ate***Customer :)

Comment: @RonBeyer *The problem I'm running into is that I want ValidCustomer function to work by itself and not require existing customer object.* - it's not clear whether the code works as intended.

Comment: @Rob thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately we are not using EF in this project...

Comment: @Mat'sMug the code is working fine. I'm just looking for an answer in terms of design patterns.

Comment: @RonBeyer This is not the actual code. I just created an example of the issue I'm running into with my current project. So, I don't think can I post it at code review.. :)

Comment: @user3587180 feel free to post your actual working code over at [codereview.se], I'm sure you'll get the kind of answers you're looking for.

Comment: @user3587180 Even without EF, I think the best approach would be to have the overload (the overload which does *not* accept an `ExistingCustomer` would load the customer and pass it to `ValidateCustomer(current,existing)`

Comment: @Rob Your answer seems to make sense. The only downside I see is that other developers reading the code might be confused seeing these overloads. But still you answer is the best option!!!

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to suggest you code or pattern until it's unclear what your existing code does. But I can suggest you some tips to consider:

1) Don't use any design patterns because someone suggested it. You need to have good understanding why and what pattern to use. You have to know at least basic and most popular ones to understand why one or another should be used.

2) I recommend to make UpdateCustomer() function of void type instead of return string error message. For errors use exceptions and handle them carefully.

3) Make sure your logic in function is correct: you do check for customer data changed and then call function recursively but without saving these changes. You will get situation when you have data changed and function is calling again and again until stack overflow. Possibly you want to call another UpdateCustomer() method that will actually save your changes in DB

4) And regarding you main question about ExistingUser and multiple DB calls dilemma:
- handle case when existingUser is null
- make sure you need existing user to validate customerToUpdate
- if you still need existing user to be used for validation why do you need to make additional DB call? Or you can select existingUser from DB in your ValidateUser() function and return isDataChanged as out parameter of this function.